# What is the role of Rate in an Admob house ad campaign

Tags: admob, ads, in-app-promotions

I have made a campaign before in the distant past but this time google has updated the design/functionality and now I have to tell a Rate even in a house ad campaign. I have set the target to 80% of total impressions, so I think my ad should be shown 80% of the time regardless of the rates of third parties.
I think I am missing something here. Please have a look at the screenshot and tell me what should I put in the Rate input box.

Basically I have made/trying to make a campaign which shows ad of another app of mine in the specified app using my personal inventory and ignoring third party ads.

[image]

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: No. But I noticed that on this rate (1) it was serving almost zero ads, then I increased it to 100 and it started serving more. Now I've set it to 20,000 and it has served significantly more ads. I think the campaign ads compete with the earning ads and only win if our rate is more than that of earning ads.

Comment: Google's not gonna charge us using admob

Comment: hmm, i have a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132190/admob-in-house-ads-not-showing