# Admob in-house ads not showing

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have set up an in-house campaign under the Admob platform. This campaign is live for almost 3 days, but I get no impressions.[image: Here is my campaign]

[image: And here is the mediation]

The ad in question is a banner. I have set up the mediation eCMP lower than the ad but still is not showing. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is error in campaign. ( In your first screenshot status column ). What error says?

Comment: status should be green. Red icon stats its inactive or behind schedule. https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6177178?ctx=tltp&hl=en#campaign-status . If it's in-house campaign - try to set eCPM to higher value

Comment: ya give it a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158326/discussion-between-amod-gokhale-and-saveandload-com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution, you need to update your billing information from AdWords in order to serve in-house ads.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Everything is green but I have 0 impressions even after a day... My app is fairly new and I have yet to cross the 70€ Limit to edit the Purchase-Information in AdMob... any Idea how I can still update my billing information?

Comment: You can, in the past was possible, check carefully.

Comment: Facing same issue. Can you help where is the "Purchase-Information in AdMob"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue even though my payment information was up to date in AdMob.
What fixed the issue for me was to set up my payment information in Google Ads which is different than AdMob. I never used Google Ads before but apparently you need to set up your payment information there (credit card info etc like if you were about to pay for ads) in order to use in house ads campaign in AdMob. I'm not sure why you would have to do that since in house ads are supposed to be free but that's eventually what fixed the issue for me, after a few, impressions started for my ad.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add billing information. if you did it but still campaign not served ads then add the minimum amount, house ads are free but you have more than 0 of your currency in your google ads account. it does not charge any amount for AdMob house ads.